# windows 2016 high availability cluster - file share not reachable from other hosts

Tags: windows, cluster, failover

I am setting up some Windows 2016 HighAvailability Cluster with FileServer Role.
I am working on virtualized hardware inside an Openstack. 
Started creating an iSCSi target and an Active Directory on the first instance, i have 2 Cluster Nodes configured in Failover Cluster Manager.

Cause all images were booted from the same source image, I needed to execute sysprep to have an unique SID.

Everything went fine while the configuration of the Storage, the nodes and the Share. I only have one big problem, I can only access the IP of the clustered FileServer from the active instance.
That means if Node1 is at the moment the active instance I can only access the share from Node1 (but with virtual Cluster IP). If I switch the active node to be Node2, it's not accessible anymore from Node1 (but therefore on Node2).

I don't see any errors in the event monitor.

I know that this is not that much information, but maybe somebody knows this kind of problem.

Is this maybe a restriction of not activated Windows? Cause the systems are not activated by now (But afaik there is no such limitation).

I configured my HA Cluster like it's described here:
https://www.1e.com/blogs/2014/08/25/creating-a-windows-cluster-part-3-creating-a-windows-failover-cluster/

So summed up, everything is working fine (also the real switching of the node if a node falls out), besides accessing the share from another host than the active node.

On ServerManager I see all Servers listed, also the Virtual Ones.

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: Please try to avoid describing an issue with a link. Also take a look at the help section, where you might find good hints on how to post a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if somebody else faces this problem. It's corresponding to the Openstack Server. Openstack by default does not except new IPs, which are not created from the OS network itself and blocks all traffic to this machines.
-> Only Accessible from the active node.

So i think that is really specific kind of problem and not corresponding to the windows cluster itself.